# Why is it asked to type repository name or database name before delete in github, dockerhub or mongodb compass

Tags: mongodb, security, github, dockerhub

Whenever we delete any repository from GitHub or DockerHub they ask us to type repository name before delete. Similarly, it happens with MongoDB Compass, If I delete a database it asks me to type database name. Why do they ask this? What kind of security is it? It is certainly not like captcha which prevents bots from automatically submitting forms. So what is the reason behind asking to type the database or repo name?

Comment: The GitHub UI contains an explanation of why they're pausing you there. Did you read it? It's not security, they're not asking you to authenticate.

Comment: Read GitHub UI explanation properly

Comment: I got the answer now. Well, I don't know why the question is marked with -ve. The question is correct and I did a few searches before asking this. Anyway, the answer is this is to make sure that a user deletes the correct repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/deleting-a-repository

tells that this is done to verify that a user deletes the correct repository.